# HttpUrlConnection Out of memory on byte allocation. Help understanding Buffered

Tags: android

I have this code I use to try to upload files more than 10mb by trying to use only 1kb on OutputStream to avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. But I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in the `while` after some bytes transfer. I would like to know why I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and how to not using lot of memory.

```
public static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url, String methode, String contenType) throws IOException {
        if(methode == null){
            methode = "POST";
        }

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(methode);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", TOKEN);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", contenType);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

        return httpURLConnection;
    }

HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = getConnection(httpsUrl, null, "application/octet-stream");
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;

        try {

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 19)
                httpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(file.length());
            else httpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) file.length());

            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            long count = 0L;

            while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1){
                bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, len);
                count += len;
                //callback for bytes uploaded
                uploadProgress.progress(count, file.length());
                //I think calling flush will release the bytes from the BufferedOutputStream
                bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            }

            String error = hasError(httpURLConnection.getErrorStream());
            if(error != null){
                throw new IOException(error);
            }

            String repons = getRepons(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            Log.d("repons uploded file", repons);

        }finally {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            if(bufferedInputStream != null)
                try {
                    bufferedInputStream.close();
                }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            if(bufferedOutputStream != null){
                try{
                    bufferedOutputStream.close();
                }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
```

My log:

```
04-16 02:39:01.526 4633-5590/ I/global: Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
04-16 02:39:01.536 4633-5590/ I/global: Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
04-16 02:39:06.687 4633-5590/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 10847 objects / 763744 bytes in 356ms
04-16 02:39:06.737 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.830MB for 784400-byte allocation
04-16 02:39:07.026 4633-4634/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1171 objects / 274736 bytes in 289ms
04-16 02:39:11.726 4633-5590/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4705 objects / 544488 bytes in 255ms
04-16 02:39:11.786 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 10.599MB for 1570832-byte allocation
04-16 02:39:12.046 4633-4634/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5 objects / 88 bytes in 256ms
04-16 02:39:21.346 4633-5590/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8546 objects / 1046152 bytes in 322ms
04-16 02:39:21.446 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 12.849MB for 3143696-byte allocation
04-16 02:39:21.806 4633-4634/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11 objects / 200 bytes in 331ms
04-16 02:39:40.156 4633-5590/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 17089 objects / 2087952 bytes in 280ms
04-16 02:39:40.166 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 6289424-byte allocation
04-16 02:39:40.546 4633-5590/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24 objects / 392 bytes in 382ms
04-16 02:39:40.546 4633-5590/ E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 6289424-byte allocation.
04-16 02:39:40.556 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm: "Thread-30" prio=5 tid=14 RUNNABLE
04-16 02:39:40.566 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x43f8f1c0 self=0x331ae8
04-16 02:39:40.566 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=5590 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3437800
04-16 02:39:40.566 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:   | schedstat=( 8153745356 27960472724 3728 )
04-16 02:39:40.576 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~93)
04-16 02:39:40.576 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:218)
04-16 02:39:40.576 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$DefaultHttpOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:750)
04-16 02:39:40.586 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:224)
04-16 02:39:40.586 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:113)
04-16 02:39:40.586 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at in.guervyl.dailysongs.DropBoxApi.uploadFile(DropBoxApi.java:217)
04-16 02:39:40.596 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at in.guervyl.dailysongs.upload.thread.SongUploadThread.run(SongUploadThread.java:113)
04-16 02:39:40.856 4633-5590/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 19 objects / 8824 bytes in 249ms
04-16 02:39:40.856 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 6289424-byte allocation
04-16 02:39:41.166 4633-5590/ D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 310ms
04-16 02:39:41.186 4633-5590/ E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 6289424-byte allocation.
04-16 02:39:41.186 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm: "Thread-30" prio=5 tid=14 RUNNABLE
04-16 02:39:41.186 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x43f8f1c0 self=0x331ae8
04-16 02:39:41.186 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=5590 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3437800
04-16 02:39:41.196 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:   | schedstat=( 8345060001 28395355021 3774 )
04-16 02:39:41.196 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~93)
04-16 02:39:41.206 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:218)
04-16 02:39:41.206 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$DefaultHttpOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:750)
04-16 02:39:41.206 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:224)
04-16 02:39:41.206 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:113)
04-16 02:39:41.206 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:61)
04-16 02:39:41.216 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.close(BufferedOutputStream.java:187)
04-16 02:39:41.216 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at in.guervyl.dailysongs.DropBoxApi.uploadFile(DropBoxApi.java:238)
04-16 02:39:41.226 4633-5590/ I/dalvikvm:     at in.guervyl.dailysongs.upload.thread.SongUploadThread.run(SongUploadThread.java:113)
04-16 02:39:41.256 4633-5590/ W/dalvikvm: threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-16 02:39:41.256 4633-5590/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-30
                                                                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
                                                                         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:218)
                                                                         at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$DefaultHttpOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:750)
                                                                         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:224)
                                                                         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:113)
                                                                         at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:61)
                                                                         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.close(BufferedOutputStream.java:187)
                                                                         at in.guervyl.dailysongs.DropBoxApi.uploadFile(DropBoxApi.java:238)
                                                                         at in.guervyl.dailysongs.upload.thread.SongUploadThread.run(SongUploadThread.java:113)
04-16 02:39:44.896 4633-5590/ I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4633 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `10mb` ????? 10 milli bit?

Comment: `setFixedLengthStreamingMode`. Remove both.

Comment: 10 megabits or megabytes

Comment: @greenapps I commented the `setFixedLengthStreamingMode` lines but I got the same errors.

Comment: `10 megabits or megabytes` ? So you really dont know the size of your file?

Comment: My application will be able to upload upto 10 megabytes. But now I am testing the application by uploading a 3 megabytes mp3 file.

Comment: So 3 MB. Remove the `flush()`.

Comment: I already commented the `flush()` but I still get the error. I don't know if `HttpUrlConnection` keep the bytes in the buffer even if the bytes have been transferred, if so I would like to free the buffer. The problem comes from the `write(bytes, 0, len)` because when I comment that line, I get no error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109332/discussion-between-user3502626-and-greenapps).

Comment: At which `count` does the error come up?

Comment: Replace the buffered output stream by a data output stream.

Comment: The count comes up **1827840** on **4102476**. From that code `Log.d("count",""+count+"/"+file.length());` The latest output is `D/count: 1827840/4102476`

Comment: Did not work neither by changing BufferedOutputStream to DataOutputStream. `D/count: 3143680/4102476`

Comment: **Note:** The entire code I posted works on my phone with 1gb ram. That test is on an Android emulator. Is it because I am on an emulator or it doesn't matter because it will give the same error on smaller devices?

Comment: The emulator datails:
`CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi)
Target: Android 2.2 (API level 8)
Skin: 240x320
SD Card: 100M
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
vm.heapSize: 16
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Generic
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
tag.id: default
hw.camera.back: none
hw.mainKeys: yes
AvdId: 240x320_ldpi_qvga
hw.camera.front: none
hw.lcd.density: 120
hw.ramSize: 512
hw.trackBall: no`

Comment: Oh on an emulator. My gd why didnt you tell that before? And that it was ok on a device. Dont take emulators serious please. And give important info straight away please.

Comment: Thank you for your help. One last thing.  So Running my application on a real device with small Ram will not give OutofMemoryError trying to upload large file using that code?